# Is there a way to concatenate expressions in str.match in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Am looking to match if a particular string has at least one digit, one upper, and one lower excluding symbols '%^&$#' and white spaces. So I am using str.match? I wonder if there is a one liner instead of && .. && .. concatenating expressions like `data.match?(/\d+|[[:upper:]]|[[:lower:]]|\w+/)` does not seem to be working.

```
def chkin(data)
  if data.match?(/\d+/) \
      && data.match?(/[[:upper:]]+/) \
      && data.match?(/[[:lower:]]+/) \
      && data.match?(/\w+/) \
      && data.length >= 10

    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

Also the \w+ alpha numeric does not work with: `"2aA1b%%sdf3123!!"` >> True when it should be false.

Comment: What's an "alphn"?

Comment: *alphn = alphanumeric

Comment: You need to be more precise about which groups of characters you wish to be present. If you require at least one lower case letter, one upper case letter and one digit, referring to an alphanumeric character seems redundant. Also, don't forget that word characters (`\w`) include underscores. In your example you refer the length of the string, but say nothing about that as a requirement. Please clarify with an edit.

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't expect `/\w+/` to not match `"2aA1b%%sdf3123!!"`. `/\w+/` equals `[A-Za-z0-9_]+`, since the strings includes at least one of those characters it will match. Could you elaborate your expectation?

Comment: But I want to exclude the symbols '%%!!%%', I want the function to return True only if the string contains [0-9][a-z][A-Z]

Comment: I guess you don't mean "**only if** the string contains `\w+`" then, but rather "if the string **contains only** `\w+`". This can be solved by adding the `\A` and `\z` anchors, which will match the beginning and ending of the string `/\A\w+\z/`. Alternative you could reverse the reverse `!data.match?(/[^[:alnum:]]/)` would also work for example.

Comment: ^ See the [anchors documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/doc/regexp_rdoc.html#label-Anchors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a regular expression containing three *positive lookaheads*:

```
r = /(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)/

"abcDE27f".match?(r) #=> true
"abcde27f".match?(r) #=> false
"ABCDE27F".match?(r) #=> false
"abcDEfgh".match?(r) #=> false
```

You can add other requirements with additional positive lookaheads. For example, if the string must be between 8 and 10 characters in length, you could add

```
(?=.{8,10}\z)
```

If you only want the string to contain alphanumic characters add

```
(?=\p{Alnum}+\z)
```

or put `\A\p{Alnum}+\z` at the end of the regex.

Comment: Thanks Cary, I just learned about lookaheads. Looks far better.

Comment: x300, positive lookaheads are powerful, but don’t overlook negative ones, which can be used in many wondrous ways.